# не качает с торент трекера файл

Tags: php, curl

Не скачивается торент файл.

Выдает ошибку: "Скачивание возможно только со страниц трекера. Попробуйте перейти на страницу с раздачей и кликнуть на ссылку для скачивания торрент-файла."

Уже все что можно перепробовал, ничего не выходит.

Выкладываю рабочий код

```
<?php

function downloadFile($data, $dataAuth)
{

    // Авторизация если нет куки файла
    if(!file_exists($dataAuth['cookieFile']))
    {
        $ch1 = curl_init($dataAuth['login_url']); 
        curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $dataAuth['post']);
        curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $dataAuth['cookieFile']);
        curl_exec($ch1);
        curl_close($ch1);
    }

    // Скачиваем файл
    $ch = curl_init($data['url']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $data['referer_header']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $dataAuth['cookieFile']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $data['urlReferer']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
    // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $handle = fopen($file, 'a'));

    echo $out = curl_exec($ch);
    $error = curl_error($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($error);
    echo '</pre>';
}

// Данные для скачивания торент файта
$data['url'] = 'http://pornolab.net/forum/dl.php?t=2317671';
$data['urlReferer'] = 'http://pornolab.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=2317671';
$data['fileName'] = 'D:\PornFidelity.torrent';
$data['referer_header'] = [
    "Referer:".$data['urlReferer'],
    "Host:pornolab.net",
];

// Данные для авторизации
$dataAuth['login_url'] = 'http://pornolab.net/forum/login.php';
$dataAuth['cookieFile'] = 'D:\cookie[pornolabnet].txt';
$dataAuth['post']['login_username'] = 'testa123123';
$dataAuth['post']['login_password'] = '123123';
$dataAuth['post']['login'] = 'Вход';

// Запускаем функцию
downloadFile($data, $dataAuth);
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [как скачать торрент файл с pornolab.net](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/685312/%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb-%d1%81-pornolab-net)

Comment: Забаньте вы автора, что ли ...

Comment: @Visman дубликат закрытого вопроса - это, конечно, сильно...

Comment: @PavelMayorov, а почему нет? Вопрос разве изменился?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо добавить больше заголовков. Откройте в браузере консоль во вкладке network и найдите, с какими заголовками уходит запрос на скачивание. Добавьте их все в свою функцию, должно помочь. Начните с таких заголовков, как Origin, host, refferer. Если есть заголовки навроде "X-Csrf-Token", "X-Requested-With" - их тоже необходимо подделать